# Use of undeclared identifier while setting up Facebook SDK for iOS in React Native init project

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm on Step 5: Connect App Delegate of [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#settings).

I've added the code to `AppDelegate.m` file as instructed. However, I receive the following error message: Use of undeclared identifier 'application' where the code reads application:application.

I imagine the second "application" must be replaced with something else, but I don't know what.

Here's the code currently in my `AppDeleage.m` file. The file was generated using `react-native init MyAppName` and modified following Facebook's instructions.

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"myAppName"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
              options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                               annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                    ];
    // Add any custom logic here.
    return handled;
  }

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `application:openURL:options` implementation, the parameter is named `app` and not `application`.

You can either change the parameter name in the method signature to `application`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
```

Or you can change the parameter when calling to the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` method to `app`:

```
BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                           annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
```